# How to use wget to download directory recursively, into directory with the same name as on the server?

Tags: wget

Let's say I have a URL like so:

```
https://mywebsite.com/files/myfolder
```

How do I download all the files in the *myfolder* part (which is a directory), excluding files like index files, into a directory with the same name?

I.e. I want to end up with a directory on my *computer* called myfolder with all of the contents of myfolder on the *server*.

Ideally I'd like to not have to specify the directory name (on the client) and just have wget do its thing and copy it from the server. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -v -m -np -c --no-check-certificate  "https://mywebsite.com/files/myfolder"  -O myfolder
```

The -R flag can be used to specify files you wish to reject in advance.

-R rejlist --reject rejlist
           Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.  In this case, you have to enclose the pattern into quotes to prevent your shell from expanding it, like in -A "*.mp3" or -A '*.mp3'.

Comment: Thanks but do I have to specify the directory name with -O every time? I was hoping there would be a way to copy that from the server.

Comment: Specifying an output directory is only necessary if you want a specific output directory. Wget will mirror the site without specifying an output directory.

Comment: That does not work as expected. wget says:  "WARNING: combining -O with -r or -p will mean that all downloaded content will be placed in the single file you specified." And everything is added to a single file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to use wget's `--mirror` feature:

```
wget --no-clobber --mirror --convert-links --page-requisites --reject-regex 'index.html' "https://mywebsite.com/files/myfolder"
```

Adjust the regular expression to exclude all name patterns of files you do not want.

Edit: Dang, J363, you beat me by a minute.